# Reset Opengl multisampling

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

I start using multisampling by doing

```
        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 3).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
        Display.create(new PixelFormat().withSamples(8), attribs);
        GL11.glEnable(GL13.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

How would I reset how many samples it uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either recreate the display
or
Keep your default framebuffer with no multisamples, make a framebuffer with multisample that is blitted to the default fbo, which may be recreated.